# 3D from camera matrix, disparity and extrinsic

Tags: computer-vision, geometry, projection, stereo-3d

I am trying to recover distance from an **inverse** disparity map, the camera matrix and some extrinsic parameters. I know that the cameras are 54cm apart. I wrote this code based on https://dellaert.github.io/19F-4476/proj3.html. The cameras are parallel so I believe the rotation matrix should be an identity matrix? Also, how should I change my code if I have an **inverse** disparity map instead of a normal disparity map?

```
import numpy as np

# (u,v,depth)
depth_point = np.array([[50], [50], [2], [1]])

#cemera matrix
K = np.array([[721, 0, 596],
              [0, 721, 149],
              [0, 0, 1]])

R = np.eye(3)

# Cameras are 54 cm apart
T = np.c_[np.eye(3),[-0.54,0,0]]

# Do the projection
point3d = np.dot(np.dot(np.dot(K, R), T), depth_point)
```